# VBA data parsing - regEx Loop with User defined function

Tags: vba, excel

We have imported the body of several emails (really 1000+) which has various data in them. I am looking to find a way to extract the salary range from the email. The email looks like this:

> Hello John Doe,
>
> Here is the amended email reflecting a change in the approved budgeted
>   salary.
>
> The job description has been reviewed and has been exempted from the
>   state personnel system based on performing professional work in an
>   academic or academic support work unit.
>
> The full salary range is $XX,XXX to $XXX,XXX. The approved budgeted
>   salary is $XX,XXX.
>
> This position IS NOT eligible for overtime compensation.

UPDATE UPDATE - @A.S.H. answered my original question beautifully, see his answer below. I also fixed the UDF function once I realized my error. All is working now!

Here's my code:

User Defined Function:

```
Function GetDollars(s As String, item As Long)
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "\$\d*[,\d]*\d*"
        On Error Resume Next
        If .test(s) Then Set GetDollars = .Execute(s)(item - 1)
        If Err <> 0 Then GetDollars = vbNullString
    End With
End Function
```

Loop Sub:

```
Sub salaryRanges()
'Loops through the Email Body and pull out Salary Ranges
Dim strText As String

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set selCol = Range("C1:C" & lastRow)

 For Each oRng In selCol
    strText = oRng.Value
    oRng.Offset(0, 1).Value = GetDollars(strText, 1)

Next

Set oRng = Nothing

End Sub
```

Columns(0,0) is not working it gives me mismatch errors or Object variable errors.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with `RegExp`:

```
Sub ExtractSalaryRange()
  Dim r As Range, reg As Object
  Set reg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  reg.MultiLine = True: reg.Global = True
  reg.Pattern = "^(The full salary range is )(.*)$"

  For Each r In wsData.Range("C1", wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
    If reg.test(r.Text) Then
      r.Offset(, 1).value = reg.Execute(r.Text).Item(0).SubMatches(1)
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it runs with out error but does not produce a result. When I put a watch on it, after Set reg = CreateObject it says "the wrong number of arguments" for reg.test and then in the loop skips r.offset(,1).value...... since I assume it is not returning true. Thoughts?

Comment: @JasonLeach where is the data located? Is it in column C? And how does it say *"the wrong number of arguments" for reg.test* since you say it runs without error?

Comment: The data is in column C yes, and it runs without error because it goes to the "If reg.test(r.Text) Then" and then skips down to "End If" skipping the "r.Offset.... line of code" If I am understanding right the "If reg.test" seems to not be returning true. Does that make sense? Thanks!

Comment: I should apologize and add that I am new to regexp

Comment: @JasonLeach yeah no problem. But if i test it with exactly the text in your OP the test succeeds. Would you try this little change? `For Each r In wsData.Range("C1", wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))`

Comment: also note that it will write the results in column D. And it wont match every cell in `C`, just those that have similar text to your example.

Comment: I will test that yes, I just updated my post, hopefully an easier answer. I made a UDF and manually it works but I cannot get VBA to put it into the cell. Thoughts?

Comment: I removed the "the" and it worked beautifully! Thanks!

Comment: @JasonLeach you are welcome, glad to know the problem is solved.